# more outputstream problems...raw data and odd output. what did i do wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, stream, external-accessory

I've opened the following input and output bluetooth streams using Apple's External Accessory Framework:

```
session = [[EASession alloc] initWithAccessory:acc forProtocol:protocol];

if (session){
    [[session inputStream] setDelegate:self];
    [[session inputStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[session inputStream] open];

    [[session outputStream] setDelegate:self];
    [[session outputStream] scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[session outputStream] open];
}
```

I'm writing to it like this:

```
uint8_t aByte[] = {0x02, 0x06, 0x04};
[[session outputStream] write:aByte maxLength:4];
NSLog(@"%d", aByte[2]);
```

I'm reading from it like this:

```
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
            uint8_t readBuf[128];
            memset(readBuf, 0, sizeof(readBuf));
            NSInteger numberRead = [[session inputStream] read:readBuf maxLength:3];

            if(numberRead < 0){
                NSError *error = [[session inputStream] streamError];
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else if (numberRead > 0) {
                NSLog(@"numberRead: %d", numberRead);
                NSLog(@"readBuf: %s", readBuf);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
            break;
```

I SHOULD be receiving back from the device "AA4" because it's sends me back two alpha characters followed by the 3 byte that was sent to it in the last stream event. The LCD screen on the device is reporting that it has received a 2 a 4 and a 6. And it is reporting that it sent an A and A and a 4. But "NSLog(@"readBuf: %s", readBuf);" always prints:

```
AA + a upside question mark//(can't seem to copy and paste that symbol from xcode)
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind...

I printed each byte individually instead of as a string. Printed the first two as char's and the last as a decimal. C style output is still weird to me...